# Open statement of the implication and the convention

Tags: predicate-logic, proof-theory

Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ be two open sentences over a set $M$. If $x$ is replaced by some element from $M$, then $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are closed sentences, and so is, say, $p(x)\wedge q(x)$. The statement 
$$\forall x\in M (p(x)\wedge q(x))$$
is clearly true if both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are true for each $x\in M$. There is a problem that I'd like to understand from some books. Consider the following statement
$$\forall x\in M (p(x)\implies q(x))$$
This is false if $p(x)$ is true and $q(x)$ is false for each $x\in M$, otherwise the statement is true. However, some books used a convention that the following statement 
$$p(x)\implies q(x)$$
is not an open sentence, even though it is in reality. This is because that that statement should be read as 
$$\forall x(p(x)\implies q(x))$$
where $x$ runs over a set, say $M$. One of the books says that the interpretation $p(x)\implies q(x)$ means "$q(x)$ is true for each $x$ for which $p(x)$ is true". I do not agree it completely, because the statement could be true if $p(x)$ is false and $q(x)$ is true for each $x$. Is it because that we are not interested if $p(x)$ is false or not when it comes to writing proofs?

**Questions**: Why should we use this kind of convention, and is my understanding correct about the truth value of the last statement?

Comment: See tag: "Proof theory is an area of logic that studies proof as formal mathematical objects."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Should I delete that tag? I was not sure which tags I should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Correct*.

There are two basic approaches in order to "give meaning" to *open* formulas.

According to the first one, the meaning (and the truth-value) of an open formula with respect to an interpretation $\mathfrak A$ is defined for specific "instances" of the formula.

In this case, we do not consider $p(x) \to q(x)$ but the corersponding instance obtained replacing the variable $x$ with a "name" or considering a variable assignment function $s$ that assign an object $a$ of the domain of $\mathfrak A$ to $x$.

In this case, the *satisfaction* relation holds for "instances":

> $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi [s]$.

See: Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA83), Academic Press (2nd ed. 2001), page 83.

The second case, limits the definition of meaning and truth value to *sentences*, i.e. "closed" formulas.

For open one, it adopts the convention that:

> $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi$  **iff** $\mathfrak A \vDash Cl(\varphi)$,

where $Cl(\varphi)$ is the *universal closure* of $\varphi$.

See: Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA67), Springer (5th ed. 2013), page 67.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I am a newbie to the mathematical logic. It may take time for me to read those deep books. Could you please explain what a such $\mathfrak{A}$ could be and what is $\phi$ and $\phi[s]$?

Comment: $\varphi [s]$ is the instance of the open formula $\varphi$ when to the variable $x$ it is assigned the "value" $s(x)$. Consider a formula "$x$ is a philosopher" and an assignment $s(x)=Plato$; then $\varphi[s]$ is "Plato is a philosopher".

Comment: $\mathfrak A$ is an interpretation, made of a *domain* (your set $M$) and  a way to interpret constant and other symbols of the language.